# How does user defined conversion sequence work in C++ when initializing objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

I have some question regarding user defined conversion sequence when performing copy initialization.
let's say

```
#include <iostream>
struct Doodle {
  operator char() { return 'd' };
};

struct Penta {
  Penta(double) {};
  Penta()  = default;
};

int main() {
  Doodle d; 
  Penta p = 3.34; // works
  Penta another = d;
```

}

In last line it calls conversion function on d and calls Penta(double) constructor. What if I had a constructor that takes Doodle ? Will it call operator char() or Penta that takes Doodle constructor?
I wish I could remember all those implicit conversion rules and sometimes these implicit conversions will be a headache in my opinion.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: A single implicit conversion can always be made. If more conversions are needed then it will fail.

Comment: If "_sometimes these implicit conversions will be a headache_" then mark the constructor explicit: `explicit Penta(double) {}` (otherwise it will remain a converting constructor), and then initialize by writing `Penta p{ 3.34 };` instead. Another topic: there's no need to put `;` after the functions' bodies.

Comment: If you had `Penta(Doodle)` constructor, it would be chosen by overload resolution over `Penta(double)`as a better match. "Better match" very roughly means "fewer conversions are necessary to match the type of argument to the type of the parameter". This is not specific to constructors - it's no different from `void f(double); void f(Doodle); f(d);`